# Composite key mySQL constraint

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

If I wanted to write mySQL for this database that's been already normalized, how would I add a constraint for the (Branch_ID, Employee_ID) composite key?

Branch Table

**Branch ID**
Branch Name
Address
Post Code
Town
County

Branch Employee Table

**Branch ID
Employee ID**

Employee Table

**Employee ID**
Employee First Name
Employee Surname
Employee NI No.

I made primary keys bald. I know how to make both the Branch Id and Employee ID primary keys using constraint, but should I also make the Employee_ID in the Branch Employee table a foreign key since I use it in another table?

Comment: you should add the DDL of your tables to your question. that way you will get a precise answer. you can get that with "SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a composite key to an existing table, use the code:

```
ALTER TABLE `Branch Employee`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (BranchID,Employee ID)
```

You are correct that each column in the Branch Employee table should be a foreign key as the values are used in other tables. Without the foreign key it could be possible to enter employees and branches that don't exist in their respective tables

Create the foreign keys as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `Branch Employee`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID_FK) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID);

ALTER TABLE `Branch Employee`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (BranchID_FK) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID);
```

*Edited in light of Raymond's comment:*

The order of columns in the composite key matters as a clustered index will be created with the primary key. The most selective (most queried) column of the two should go first and then less selective second. The right or wrong order will depend on the queries being run against the table

Comment: Topicstarter also don't blindly add columns in anny order when making a`composite key` the order does matter for performance... You want the most selective one first which filters out most of the records so it is depending on the queries you need

Answer (score 0):

a PRIMARY KEY is an identifier for each table.

a FOREIGN KEY means that a value ina table is referenced by a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

In this case, you need to set your Branch ID Employee ID both, PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY;
FOREIGN KEY - because they are referenced by another table.
PRIMARY KEY - because you don't want 'employee a' to be twice in 'branch a'.

Caution: You can still have 'employee a' in both 'branch a' and 'branch b'.

To avoid this, is better that Employee table contains a parameter call branch id, and become it the foreign key.

Hope it helps